# Passing props from a parent component to a child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass property from a parent component to a child component using that line of code :

```
const isPermitted = ["permitted","not-permitted"]

    const sideBar = [
        {
            id: 0, name: "Dashboard", icon: dashboard, path: `${url}/dashboard`, exact: true,
            component: () => <Dashboard isPermitted={isPermitted} />
        },
```

--Edit : here is how I loop through my sidebar array to render my routes :

```
{sideBar.map((route, index) => (
            <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.component} />
            ))}
```

The problem here is that whenever I go to the dashboard component and try to console log (props), it always shows an empty object instead of showing the array with its content accordingly. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are repeating the `isPermitted` in that condition `isPermitted={isPermitted && isPermitted}`? it should be `isPermitted={isPermitted}`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I fixed it and still not working tho.

Comment: how are you rendering that component? i mean the sidebar

Comment: I am looping through that array named sidebar to render my routes.

Comment: how do you loop ? share some code snippet

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim done :')

Comment: another question are using a class or function based component?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I am using functional component.

Comment: please check https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `render` prop instead of `component`.

```
render: props => <Dashboard {...props} isPermitted={isPermitted} />
```

Given your route creation involves `map`:

```
{sideBar.map((route, index) => {
  const Component = route.component;

  return (
    <Route
      key={index}
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact}
      render={props => <Component {...props} isPermitted={isPermitted} />} />
  );
})}
```

Comment: I am looping through my sidebar array to render my routes using the component property so I think it doesn't really matter whether the name is component or render.

Comment: It does if you're passing each component to the route as its own component. `component` assumes a `prop`-less component, whereas `render` gives you more control over exactly what is rendered.

Comment: Would you please take a look at how I implement the routes!

Comment: You can treat each `route.component` as a component in JSX. I'm assuming you cannot do `<route.component />` in JSX, so I assign it to a variable first.

Comment: Try `component:Dashboard` in sidebar array

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim still doesn't work. I am a bit disappointed as it shall be working.Why do you think this could happen?

Comment: @Saif did you try out my answer?